# Reducing the width of Dialogue fragment

Tags: android

I am creating a DialogueFragment to Display the calender, below is the code for Dialogue fragment,

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dailogue_datepicker,        container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

This this XMl for fragment_dialogue_datepicker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is the Dialogue width spans the entire screen, I just want it to wrap content.

Link to screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15jcB.jpg

Comment: Can you provide screenshot and the code related to how you show the dialog? Are you using `public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)` from `DialogFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setAttributes(windowParams);
}
```

Comment: still getting same size

Comment: Then try to add this string dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); after you show your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the fragment you are assigning that fragment to a particular view. Set the view to wrap the width. If you are using the main frame to add your fragment simply add a new view on top of it with the constraint to wrap the width. If you do not understand what I mean let me know.

```
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_frame, active, "").addToBackStack("").setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
```

In the add statement you are defining where you want the fragment to be placed. Create a fragment_frame in your XML which has the attribute to wrap the content.

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to say